# Which microformats should my blog implement?

Tags: semantics, rdf, microformats, microdata

Or microdata, RDF(a) or others.

'entities' a blog has would include posts, comments, taxonomies and users.

For posts I found [BlogPosting](http://schema.org/BlogPosting) and [hAtom](http://microformats.org/wiki/hatom), which is a draft spec.

[hCard](http://microformats.org/wiki/hcard) and [rel="tag"](http://microformats.org/wiki/rel-tag) come to mind for users and taxonomies, but what do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Big discussion in the community about this specific topic. I would go for [schema.org](http://schema.org/) - Bing's, Google's and yahoo's recent schema proposal. That is (quoting them):

> This site provides a collection of
>   schemas, i.e., html tags, that
>   webmasters can use to markup their
>   pages in ways recognized by major
>   search providers.

... see [BlogPosting](http://schema.org/BlogPosting) for their specific schema for blog postings.
 And they also provide a mapping data model to use RDFa ... [see this other one](http://schema.org/docs/datamodel.html)

More RDFa related, there is a port of [schema.org by the Linked Data comunity](http://schema.rdfs.org/) RDFa using URIs here, quoting again ...

> This site is a complementary effort by
>   people from the Linked Data community
>   to express the terms provided by the
>   Schema.org consortium in RDF. We
>   currently provide static RDFS
>   documents of the Schema.org terms in
>   the formats listed below - and yes,
>   we're heavily working on more ;)

Which one to use ? As I said, there's a big discussion going on right now around this issue.